# Unable to create and connect to own docker registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I'm trying to host a private docker registry.

I've followed: https://docs.docker.com/registry/ to create my own registry?

But when running:

```
    curl http://127.0.0.1:5000
```

It exits without error, but without result either.

Answer (score 1):

You get an empty answer, because nothing is on the root context of your registry.
If curl would fail to connect, you would get an error message. So either try

```
curl -I http://127.0.0.1:5000
```

which shows the headers returned from your curl statement (should be `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`) or

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/v2/_catalog
```

which lists the repositories of your registry. A query to an empty registry should output something like this:

```json
{"repositories":[]}
```